# Delete rows based on count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in `MYSQL` it contains following fields:

```
issue_id int(11),
label_id int(11)
```

in this table I'd like to delete rows based on the count of a certain field if the count is 2 delete it otherwise don't

```
DELETE FROM issue_labels 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT count(*) c, 
            `issue_id` 
            FROM `issue_labels` 
            GROUP BY `issue_id`
            ) temp 
ON issue_labels.issue_id = temp.issue_id 
WHERE c = 2
```

The above SQL throws an error, but if I do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM issue_labels 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT count(*) c, 
            `issue_id` 
            FROM `issue_labels` 
            GROUP BY `issue_id`) temp 
ON issue_labels.issue_id = temp.issue_id 
WHERE c = 2
```

It works! What I want to say is, that join works but the delete command does not.

I've also tried using subquery like:

```
DELETE FROM issue_labels 
WHERE issue_id IN (
 SELECT `issue_id` 
  FROM `issue_labels` 
  GROUP BY `issue_id` 
 HAVING count(*) = 2
 )
```

But this throws an error, the message is:

> "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'issue_labels' for update in FROM clause"

Moreover, I'd prefer a solution that uses join instead of nesting as I believe join is more efficient than subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
DELETE issue_labels
FROM issue_labels 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT count(*) c, 
            `issue_id` 
            FROM `issue_labels` 
            GROUP BY `issue_id`
            ) temp 
ON issue_labels.issue_id = temp.issue_id 
WHERE c = 2
```

**Explanation:**

The join forces you to use "DELETE issue_labels FROM issue_labels" instead of the normal "DELETE FROM issue_labels", since the table to delete is no longer unambiguous.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "since the table to delete is no longer unambiguous"? Your query worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure... Since you want to delete using join so you have to provide from which table you want to delete the records out of tables in join condition.

Comment: So, if I join 2 tables A and B in a delete query, I'll have to specify whether I want to delete records from A or B, if I have to delete from A i'll write DELETE A FROM..., have i got it right?